# How Can I Change XML to JSON?

Tags: java, xml, xml-serialization

I am creating a web service client from a WSDL, and I want to transform the XML that I get from a SOAP call, into a JSON object (as a RESTful WS).

I've tried GSON, but it insists on a TypeAdapter.  Since I have about 75 objects, I need something that is more generic.  I have also used Jackson, but it just sends it across unchanged as XML.

NetBeans (wsimport) generates many classes, and example of which is shown below.  How can I turn this into a JSON object?

```
  import javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement;
  import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
  import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
  import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
  import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElementRef;
  import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;


  @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
  @XmlType(name = "addressData", propOrder = {
      "addressLine1",
      "addressLine2"
  })
  public class AddressData {

      @XmlElement(required = true)
      protected String addressLine1;
      @XmlElementRef(name = "addressLine2", type = JAXBElement.class, required = false)
      protected JAXBElement<String> addressLine2;

      /**
       * Gets the value of the addressLine1 property.
       * 
       * @return
       *     possible object is
       *     {@link String }
       *     
       */
      public String getAddressLine1() {
          return addressLine1;
      }

      /**
       * Sets the value of the addressLine1 property.
       * 
       * @param value
       *     allowed object is
       *     {@link String }
       *     
       */
      public void setAddressLine1(String value) {
          this.addressLine1 = value;
      }

      /**
       * Gets the value of the addressLine2 property.
       * 
       * @return
       *     possible object is
       *     {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link String }{@code >}
       *     
       */
      public JAXBElement<String> getAddressLine2() {
          return addressLine2;
      }

      /**
       * Sets the value of the addressLine2 property.
       * 
       * @param value
       *     allowed object is
       *     {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link String }{@code >}
       *     
       */
      public void setAddressLine2(JAXBElement<String> value) {
          this.addressLine2 = value;
      }

  }
```

Comment: "I have also used Jackson, but it just sends it across unchanged as XML." Then you have not properly configured jackson; it can handle JAXB annotations. What did you try?

Comment: I was under the impression that it was automatic if I used the @ResponseBody notation in my method signature.  Can you tell me what action I need to take with Jackson?

Comment: If you're using spring-mvc 3.1 and have `mvc:annotation-driven` in your config, it may be automatic, but you still need to ensure you send the correct HTTP headers (`Accept: application/json`). If you have done this and it's still not automatic, you may have to configure `AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter` with a jackson `messageConverter`

Comment: That was the answer (AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter with a jackson messageConverter).  Thanks much.

Answer (score 0):

You may have to configure `AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter` with a jackson messageConverter:

```
<bean id="jsonConverter" class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter">
    <property name="objectMapper" ref="jacksonObjectMapper"/>
    <property name="supportedMediaTypes">
        <list>
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.MediaType">
                <constructor-arg index="0" value="application"/>
                <constructor-arg index="1" value="json"/>
                <constructor-arg index="2" value="UTF-8"/>
            </bean>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
    <property name="messageConverters">
        <list>
            <ref bean="jsonConverter"/>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```